# Handle offfsets in a function

Tags: c, function, pointers

I now paraphrased the question clearly below:

Initially, I was dealing with offsets for a matrix of 16X32 bytes that would get applied in the function below. The below function is simplified form of what I am doing as that will give a clear idea of I am trying to do here.

Offests: 0, 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56 vertically at positions 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7.

So, I had defined them as macros:

```
#define X1 0 * 8
#define X2 1 * 8
#define X3 2 * 8
............
#define X7 7 * 8
```

simplified code:(Actually using all the above offsets and have 3 different functions using these offset values to determine something. But only demonstrated one below as that should be sufficient enough)

```
function(uint8 *ubase)
{
    if (((*(ubase + X3)) - *((ubase + X7))) != 
    (*((ubase + X2)) - *((ubase + X6)))  
    and so on ....)
    {
        Statements1;
        Statements2;
    }
    else
    {
        Statements3;
        Statements4;
    }            
}
```

Now, I need apply different sets of offsets based on a flag. i.e. If bool bType is TRUE use the Offsets above else Use a different set. Fortunately, the newer set that will get applied is just 2 * each offset value above.

I know Macros are used only when we need to use constants multiple times in a program.

one way to do it is something like below:

Since the newer and older offset has a similarity, I can still retain the macros part and check a condition in the simplied code like

```
if ((*((ubase + (X3 * (TRUE == bType ? 0 : 2)))))...........)
```

However, as I mentioned above there are several occurrences of the offsets and doing the above way means the condition needs to be checked at all of its occurrences. Since there are about 20 such occurrences, wondering it it is a good practice to do it this way.

Is the above method a good practice to address the offset handling problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is it that you would like to do?

Comment: If you don't even have code yet, it's too soon to worry about which way is fastest.

Comment: "how I can proceed with this" - proceed with what?

Comment: I previously had them as constants but now looks like it needs to be handled as a variable. I would like to know of an efficient method to handle the offsets in the same funciton.

Comment: I have no idea what are you talking about...

Comment: What do you mean by "handle the offsets"?

Comment: Is "matrix of size" a polite way to call a matrix fat?

Answer (score 1):

This?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int set1[] = {0 << 0, 8 << 0, 16 << 0, 32 << 0, 48 << 0};
    int set2[] = {0 << 1, 8 << 1, 16 << 1, 32 << 1, 48 << 1};
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("%d %d\n", set1[i], set2[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can not change a `#define` value at runtime based on the input, it is not clear to me, if you want a progression based on the input, why not multiply `8 * 4` in order to get the fourth element in your array?